# Word count in C, learning more CS

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, malloc, information-retrieval

After about 5 years of programming in dynamic languages such as Python and JS I am starting to feel I'm missing out of what happens under the hood. Languages such as these are really great because they let you focus on what you have to do leveraging the trouble of working with pointers, memory allocation and many searching, sorting, inserting algorithms. Even though I never regret using these languages as I really feel they are ridiculously powerful I feel that, in order to become a better programmer, I need to take a step back and understand what happens under the hood!

I decided to do this by writing a simple word counter: The app gets all the params and outputs all the unique words, each one with a counter: "Hello world Hello" would return "Hello: 2", "world: 1" (not taking in consideration the actual output structure). This program is the Python equivalent of:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def main():
    results = defaultdict(int)
    for word in sys.argv[1:]:
        results[word] += 1
    print results
```

Writing it in C is a bit different, I feel like I'm getting something utterly wrong with pointers, arrays of pointers and all that stuff! I want to get better, Help me get better!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// This is what a key-value pair: <int, string>
typedef struct {
    int counter;
    unsigned char* word;
} hashmap;

// Checks if inside the array of results, hashmap->word is equals to word paramter
hashmap* get_word_from_results(hashmap* results[], int count, const char* word) {
    int i;
    hashmap* result;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result = results[i];
        if (result->word == (unsigned char *)word)
            return result;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    hashmap* results;
    int results_counter = 0;

    int i;
    const char* word;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        word = argv[i];
        hashmap* result = get_word_from_results(&results, results_counter, word);
        // If result is NULL, means word is not inserted yet, let's create a new hashmap and insert it inside the array
        if (result == NULL) {
            hashmap h;
            h.counter = 1;
            h.word = (unsigned char *)word;

            results = realloc(NULL, (results_counter + 1) * sizeof(hashmap) );
            // NOTE: potential memory leak? would h be deallocated?
            results[results_counter] = h;
            results_counter++;
            printf("NEW\n");
        } else {
            // The word already exists in the hashmap array, let's increase it by 1
            result->counter++;
            printf("INCREMENTED\n");
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice? what am I doing wrong here? Are my pointers okay? also I think I spotted a memory leak (see comments), would anyone like to submit their version??

Thanks!! you guys are so cool!!

Daniel

Comment: 1) You are comparing pointers. You should compare the strings that they point to. Hint: use strcmp(). 2) on insertion, you first set the counter to 1, and increment it as well. 3) you are also assigning pointers. hint: strdup()

Comment: We are indeed way cool here.  One of the ways we preserve our coolness is being strict about what we let through the front door of the club; we don't let vague, broad or off-topic questions in for one thing.  Your question is exceedingly vague, better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1 perhaps.  We're so cool we only answer precise questions about precise programming problems.

Comment: You may already have realized, but just pointing it out -- you call this data structure hashmap but then do a linear search of it, which isn't really how a hash table ought to work.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You'r right. I'm really sorry. Apologies for not having seen this. Is there anyway I can migrate my question?

Comment: If all else fails, delete here and repost there.  I've never migrated a question myself so can offer no better advice.

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys!! Looking into it!

Comment: @FatalError I know exactly what you mean. I was planning for now to get it working, and then optimize it more.

Comment: I dont really get the point of this - how is this going to help you if you dont intent to switch to lower level language?

Comment: I just think that dynamic languages do a lot of work for you. I don't intend to reproduce this work every time but I definitely want to learn how it works. I think it could make me a better programmer too.

Comment: @PirosB3: I'd ignore Ulterior's comment, this is definitely a valuable exercise! Keep at it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Performance Mark waned to let you know that I re-posted the question on CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/word-count-in-c-learning-more-cs I'm sorry for having pasted it in the wrong place but I did not appreciate the -1 you or someone else gave me. Was it you?

Comment: As it happens I rarely downvote questions and didn't downvote this.  But if you come to SO you have to play by our rules, your question is off-topic (hence the close votes).  If you don't like being downvoted, write better questions.  Oh, and get a thicker skin !

Answer (score 1):

The major pointer issue in your program is that when `hashmap* results` is passed to `realloc` for the first time, its value is uninitialized. This is undefined behavior. You should initialize the pointer to `NULL`, like this:

```
hashmap* results = NULL;
```

The other problem is comparing strings: you need to use `strcmp` rather than `==`. Remember that `strcmp` returns zero when strings are equal.

There are also memory leaks at the end of your program. You should free `results`, along with the words that are stored inside its elements.

Of course the thing that you call `hashmap` behaves precisely like a dynamic array. Programming a hash table in C presents a different level of challenge, however, so I would encourage you to make your current approach work.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I think there is a problem with the actual structure of hashmap! unsigned char* word; <-- This is a Pointer to a single char. I want it to point to an array of chars (string for us python guys) but I don't know the actual size of each string! What would you suggest me to do? Thanks on the hints!

Comment: @PirosB3 `char*` is the right type: strings in C are zero-terminated sequences of `char`s, so the first character is at the pointer, the second character is at pointer plus one, the third is at pointer plus two, and so on, until you hit a zero byte, which means the end of the string has been reached.

Comment: Groovy! does that only work with char or with everything else? how do I do pointer +1 ?

Comment: This works for everything else. You do pointer plus one just like this: `ptr+1`. This is the same as `&ptr[1]`, because pointers can be re-interpreted as arrays, and arrays can be re-interpreted as pointers.

Comment: OK then: let's say I have a pointer to an array of integers, is this correct?: int* integer; Once it's assigned to an array of integers I want to loop through the array, What will be the difference from adding 1 to the actual number and adding 1 to the pointer?  what would integer++ do?

Comment: @PirosB3 if you have `int *ptr = ...`, `ptr+1` means "pointer plus one", `*ptr+1` means "integer plus one", and `*(ptr+1)` means "integer located at pointer plus one". Of course "plus one" on an integer pointer means "plus one integer", which means "plus four" on a 32-bit system, "plus two" on a 16-bit system, and so on. In general, "pointer plus N" means "pointer plus N times the size of the value the pointer points to".